# Counting listView items error

Tags: android, listview, counting

I am trying to count listView items. Im using this code:

```
int count=0;
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
 for(int i = 0; i  <= listView.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++)
         {
             if(listView.getChildAt(i)!= null)
             {
                 count++;  
             }
         }

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(count), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Why the COUNT variable value is always  0, when listView display some records?

Comment: listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == 0 ???

Comment: ListView is populated from ListAdapter, which has method getCount(). Is that what you need? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for count of all ListView items, you can use this call (make sure adapter is set):

```
listView.getCount();
```

If what you want is count of visible items, try this (works only for visible ListView):

```
listView.getLastVisiblePosition()-listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain the reason..
You've just get the listview like this

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

so listview has no elements and then you are tring to get the last visible postion by using  `listView.getLastVisiblePosition()` it always returns zero because your listview hasn't yet bind with any adapter, i.e your listview is empty at the time your are getting the last visible position try to `place this code after binding Adapter to the listview`

```
for(int i = 0; i  <= listView.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++)
         {
             if(listView.getChildAt(i)!= null)
             {
                 count++;  
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this .It helps mine

```
String CountListRowNo= String.valueOf(+ListviewObj.getAdapter().getCount());
```